# BlackBerry - How to make socket keep alive for infinite time

Tags: networking, sockets, blackberry, connection-timeout

I have created socket program in Blackberry. and also set socket to keep alive using the following

```
socket = (SocketConnection) Connector.open(URL);
socket.setSocketOption(socket.KEEPALIVE, 2);
```

But my socket connection gets terminated after 2-3 minute. Means if I keep Ideal for 2-3 minute for 2-3 minute then my socket connection gets lost.

So how to make my socket connection to be alive forever although I may be ideal for 1 hour or more than that.

Comment: Im facing exactly the same problem...any solution?

Comment: You've asked 13 questions and haven't accepted any answers yet. Surely some of the were helpful. The one below from coldice for example is definitive. Perhaps time to repay those who have helped you most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How To - Control the connection timeout for TCP connections through the BlackBerry MDS Connection Service](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/How_To_-_Control_the_connection_timeout_for_TCP_connections_through_BlackBerry_Mobile_Data_System_Connection_Service.html?nodeid=1235131&vernum=0)

Comment: The link is invalid. Where can I find this article?